# array iteration in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is my code

```
$('select.more-search').each(function(i, e){ 
    more_srch[i] = $(this).attr('name'); 
    $('#'+more_srch[i]+' :selected').each(function(j, selected){ 
      more_sel[i][j] = $(selected).val(); 
    });
});
```

It shows error in console as 
`TypeError: more_sel[i] is undefined`

How to remove this error?

Comment: What exactly you need? Have you defined `more_sel`?

Comment: what are you trying to do here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize `more_sel[i]` to an empty array before you can assign to elements.

```
$('select.more-search').each(function(i, e){ 
    more_srch[i] = $(this).attr('name'); 
    more_sel[i] = [];
    $('#'+more_srch[i]+' :selected').each(function(j, selected){ 
      more_sel[i][j] = $(selected).val(); 
    });
});
```

Instead of using `.each()`, you could use `.map()`:

```
 $('select.more-search').each(function(i, e){ 
    more_srch[i] = $(this).attr('name'); 
    more_sel[i] = $('#'+more_srch[i]+' :selected').map(function(j, selected){ 
      return $(selected).val(); 
    }).get(); // use .get() to turn returned jQuery object into normal array
});
```